# omnetpp won't run on macOS after fresh installation

Tags: omnet++

i installed omnetpp 5.6.2 on macOS m1, but it won't start after installation. The ide also would not start. Is there anyway I can fix this issue?

I tired to run from the ide subfolder but it still did not start.

Answer (score 1):

As the installation guide states: OMNeT++ 5.6.2 does NOT support M1 macs. Use 5.7 which has workarounds to start in x86 emulation mode.